# Token from Header is null in chrome and in IE11 it is work fine

Tags: angular

I have an web app ( using spring boot on back-end and angular 2 on front-end). 
 My problem: I am trying to store in local storage the token which is send from the server... the token is received in the header but when I try to get it from the header it is null in google chrome, but in IE 11 it's working fine...

```
//service.ts
    @Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private _http : Http) { }

  loginUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', JSON.stringify(user));
  }
}
```

here is where I am trying to save in local storage and also to print in console(in console is null and also in local storage is saved as null)

```
 //login.componenet.ts 
onLoginSucces(response) {
        console.log(response.headers.get("X-AUTH-TOKEN"));
        localStorage.setItem('auth-token',response.headers.get("X-AUTH-TOKEN"));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('auth-token'));
        this.loggedIn=true;
        this.loginStatus = true;
        this._router.navigateByUrl("/home");
      }

      onLogFailed(error) {
        console.log(error.status);
        this.loginStatus = false;
      }


      onLogin() {
        this._loginService.loginUser(this.userLogin).
        subscribe(
          data => this.onLoginSucces(data),
          err => this.onLogFailed(err)
          );
      }
```

may be i have a problem in CORS but I don't think so( it is working on IE 11)

```
//CORSFilter.java
public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {

      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "Content-Type, x-requested-with, X-AUTH-TOKEN");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-AUTH-TOKEN");

    } else {

      chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJiDQ.png)here is a picture with the Header response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but somehow the google chrome must have installed the allow-controll-origin extension